# Capture in aspectj a method invocation within a catch

Tags: handler, aspectj

I would like to know if a specific method is invoked within a catch, that is, to capture a method's call that takes place within a catch. Is It posible? 
Thank you!
Bea

Comment: Welcome to SO. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is your friend because it is much more likely to yield meaningful answers than just one or two sentences of abstract prose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a [`handler()` pointcut](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5298) in AspectJ, but it does not work in connection with `cflow()` and also only in `before()` advices as of today (version 1.9.2). The question is interesting, though, so I created an Bugzilla [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546167) for it.

Comment: Thank you very much @kriegaex. I have already tried with `cflow(handler(..))` and realised that it does not work. Lets see if next AspectJ release will support it.

Comment: Thanks Bea, you can accept and upvote my answer, but not change someone else's vote, of course. That would not be democratic.